# Will mod_rewrite to an image on another domain cost bandwidth for the original domain?

Tags: mod-rewrite, amazon-s3, bandwidth

I want to use mod_rewrite to include a date in an image filename, so browsers will know to refresh an image anytime it's changed, despite any expires headers.

My rewrite rule is

`RewriteRule ^images/[0-9]+/(.*)$ http://my-amazon-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/$1`

which should turn something like

`http://example.com/images/2010-08-11/example-image.jpg`

into

`http://my-amazon-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/example-image.jpg`

**Will the first domain be carrying the bandwidth of the entire image file?**

Comment: I don't think so, one the request is made client will be redirected before the image is serverd from that domain.

Comment: I stumbled upon one of your old question, and i am having a tiny problem with mine here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29898156/1478789, basically i am trying to do image rewrite just like you without success. Can you perhaps help me? I really appreciate it. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule will result in a response that tells the client to send another to the target location to retrieve the resource from there (see [HTTP response status code 302](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)).

Only if you’re using a proxy (using the [*P* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_p), see also [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)) your server would request the resource from remote and pass it to the client, resulting in doubling the in- and output.

Answer (score 0):

the first client gets the request, but then passes it onto the second.  So the bandwidth to provide the image would be handled by the second host.